# UITextField as title view in UITableViewControllers embedded in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` whose pages are a bunch of `UITableViewController`. I want to use a `UITextField` as the title field for each of my table view.

In my `UIPageViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, I have the following:

```
let titleField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 21))
titleField.delegate = self
titleField.placeholder = "(table name)"
navigationItem.titleView = titleField
```

This works and the text field shows up, but I'd like each of the page (i.e UITableViewController) to handle its own title view. So I moved the above code into my `UITableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, but now nothing shows up.. Why?

Any input would be great. I guess I could keep track of which page I'm currently in in my `UIPageViewController` but I'm trying to avoid that. It's a lot of bookkeeping that I don't need.

Comment: The `navigationItem` and its properties are only useful if the given view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Then is there anyway I can access the `UIPageViewController` from its pages?

Comment: You'll create many text fields. Just create one and change its text when move to a new page.